# bchart: too big - fit in 2 pages

Tags: subcaption, legend, bchart

I am trying to create a big bar chart including 32 items. How could I split it in two pages? I've tried to divide it on the 16th by using `subfigure` (as below); though, it doesn't split in two pages.

Secondly, how can I add a legend using `bchart` package?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{bchart}[max = 55, step = 10, scale=0.8]
\bcbar{49.8}
\bcbar[label=Greece, color=green!70!blue]{28.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{24.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{48.3}
\bcbar[label=Spain, color=green!70!blue]{23.6}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{22.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{43}
\bcbar[label=Croatia, color=green!70!blue]{17}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{16.3}
\smallskip
\bcbar{40.3}
\bcbar[label=Italy, color=green!70!blue]{12.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{11.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{32.8}
\bcbar[label=Cyprus, color=green!70!blue]{14.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{15}
\smallskip
\bcbar{32}
\bcbar[label=Portugal, color=green!70!blue]{12.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{12.6}
\smallskip
\bcbar{26.5}
\bcbar[label=Slovakia, color=green!70!blue]{12.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{11.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{24.7}
\bcbar[label=France, color=green!70!blue]{9.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{10.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{22.4}
\bcbar[label=EURO Area, color=green!70!blue]{11}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{10.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Latvia, color=green!70!blue]{8.6}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{22.4}
\bcbar[label=Finland, color=green!70!blue]{8.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.9}
\bcbar[label=Ireland, color=green!70!blue]{7.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.3}
\bcbar[label=EU (28 countries), color=green!70!blue]{9.5}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{21.6}
\bcbar[label=Bulgaria, color=green!70!blue]{8.4}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Lithuania, color=green!70!blue]{8.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Slovenia, color=green!70!blue]{10.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{8.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{22.1}
\bcbar[label=Belgium, color=green!70!blue]{7.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{8.5}
\smallskip
\end{bchart}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}


\begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{bchart}[max = 55, step = 10, scale=0.8]
\bcbar{20.8}
\bcbar[label=Poland, color=green!70!blue]{7.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{7.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.4}
\bcbar[label=Sweden, color=green!70!blue]{7.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{7.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{11.3}
\bcbar[label=Netherlands, color=green!70!blue]{7.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{21.7}
\bcbar[label=Romania, color=green!70!blue]{5.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.8}
\smallskip
\bcbar{17.3}
\bcbar[label=Hungary, color=green!70!blue]{7.0}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.8}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.6}
\bcbar[label=Luxembourg, color=green!70!blue]{7.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{13.1}
\bcbar[label=Estonia, color=green!70!blue]{6.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{10.8}
\bcbar[label=Denmark, color=green!70!blue]{6.4}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{10.6}
\bcbar[label=Austria, color=green!70!blue]{5.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.7}
\smallskip
\bcbar{11.8}
\bcbar[label=Malta, color=green!70!blue]{5.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{14.6}
\bcbar[label=United Kingdom, color=green!70!blue]{5.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.3}
\smallskip
\bcbar{12.6}
\bcbar[label=Czech Republic, color=green!70!blue]{6.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{7.2}
\bcbar[label=Germany, color=green!70!blue]{4.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.6}
\smallskip
\bcbar{9.9}
\bcbar[label=Norway, color=green!70!blue]{4.0}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{8.8}
\bcbar[label=Iceland, color=green!70!blue]{4.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.0}
\smallskip
\end{bchart}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Unemployment rate: 2015}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `figure` environment cannot split across pages, and neither can a `bchart` environment. You will need to split it across multiple `figure` environments.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

There are two different suggestions in this answer, so scroll to the end. The legend is only implemented in the second suggestion, but you can use the same technique for the first.

## Split across two pages

A `figure` environment cannot split across pages, so just using two `subfigure` environments isn't enough. Use two `figure` environments, remove the `subfigure` environments, and use `\ContinuedFloat` in the second `figure`. You still need to scale it down more than you have already to make half the chart fit in one page though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{subcaption}    
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\renewcommand\bcfontstyle{\sffamily\scriptsize}
\begin{bchart}[max = 55, step = 10, scale=0.6]
\bcbar{49.8}
\bcbar[label=Greece, color=green!70!blue]{28.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{24.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{48.3}
\bcbar[label=Spain, color=green!70!blue]{23.6}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{22.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{43}
\bcbar[label=Croatia, color=green!70!blue]{17}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{16.3}
\smallskip
\bcbar{40.3}
\bcbar[label=Italy, color=green!70!blue]{12.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{11.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{32.8}
\bcbar[label=Cyprus, color=green!70!blue]{14.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{15}
\smallskip
\bcbar{32}
\bcbar[label=Portugal, color=green!70!blue]{12.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{12.6}
\smallskip
\bcbar{26.5}
\bcbar[label=Slovakia, color=green!70!blue]{12.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{11.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{24.7}
\bcbar[label=France, color=green!70!blue]{9.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{10.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{22.4}
\bcbar[label=EURO Area, color=green!70!blue]{11}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{10.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Latvia, color=green!70!blue]{8.6}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{22.4}
\bcbar[label=Finland, color=green!70!blue]{8.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.9}
\bcbar[label=Ireland, color=green!70!blue]{7.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.3}
\bcbar[label=EU (28 countries), color=green!70!blue]{9.5}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{21.6}
\bcbar[label=Bulgaria, color=green!70!blue]{8.4}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Lithuania, color=green!70!blue]{8.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Slovenia, color=green!70!blue]{10.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{8.5}
\end{bchart}
\caption{Unemployment rate: 2015}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\ContinuedFloat
\renewcommand\bcfontstyle{\sffamily\scriptsize}
\begin{bchart}[max = 55, step = 10, scale=0.6]
\bcbar{22.1}
\bcbar[label=Belgium, color=green!70!blue]{7.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{8.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.8}
\bcbar[label=Poland, color=green!70!blue]{7.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{7.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.4}
\bcbar[label=Sweden, color=green!70!blue]{7.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{7.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{11.3}
\bcbar[label=Netherlands, color=green!70!blue]{7.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{21.7}
\bcbar[label=Romania, color=green!70!blue]{5.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.8}
\smallskip
\bcbar{17.3}
\bcbar[label=Hungary, color=green!70!blue]{7.0}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.8}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.6}
\bcbar[label=Luxembourg, color=green!70!blue]{7.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{13.1}
\bcbar[label=Estonia, color=green!70!blue]{6.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{10.8}
\bcbar[label=Denmark, color=green!70!blue]{6.4}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{10.6}
\bcbar[label=Austria, color=green!70!blue]{5.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.7}
\smallskip
\bcbar{11.8}
\bcbar[label=Malta, color=green!70!blue]{5.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{14.6}
\bcbar[label=United Kingdom, color=green!70!blue]{5.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.3}
\smallskip
\bcbar{12.6}
\bcbar[label=Czech Republic, color=green!70!blue]{6.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{7.2}
\bcbar[label=Germany, color=green!70!blue]{4.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.6}
\smallskip
\bcbar{9.9}
\bcbar[label=Norway, color=green!70!blue]{4.0}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{8.8}
\bcbar[label=Iceland, color=green!70!blue]{4.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.0}
\smallskip
\end{bchart}
\caption{Unemployment rate: 2015}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Two columns

I don't know your requirements, but if you scale it down a bit, and split it over to `bchart` environments you can fit it in one page, by having two charts next to one another.

From a cursory glance at the manual, it doesn't look like `bchart` has any ways of making a legend, but it's built around TikZ, so you could add a `matrix` manually, see near end of code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\renewcommand\bcfontstyle{\sffamily\scriptsize}
\centering
\begin{bchart}[max = 55, step = 10, scale=0.5]
\bcbar{49.8}
\bcbar[label=Greece, color=green!70!blue]{28.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{24.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{48.3}
\bcbar[label=Spain, color=green!70!blue]{23.6}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{22.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{43}
\bcbar[label=Croatia, color=green!70!blue]{17}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{16.3}
\smallskip
\bcbar{40.3}
\bcbar[label=Italy, color=green!70!blue]{12.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{11.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{32.8}
\bcbar[label=Cyprus, color=green!70!blue]{14.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{15}
\smallskip
\bcbar{32}
\bcbar[label=Portugal, color=green!70!blue]{12.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{12.6}
\smallskip
\bcbar{26.5}
\bcbar[label=Slovakia, color=green!70!blue]{12.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{11.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{24.7}
\bcbar[label=France, color=green!70!blue]{9.9}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{10.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{22.4}
\bcbar[label=EURO Area, color=green!70!blue]{11}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{10.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Latvia, color=green!70!blue]{8.6}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{22.4}
\bcbar[label=Finland, color=green!70!blue]{8.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.9}
\bcbar[label=Ireland, color=green!70!blue]{7.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.3}
\bcbar[label=EU (28 countries), color=green!70!blue]{9.5}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{21.6}
\bcbar[label=Bulgaria, color=green!70!blue]{8.4}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Lithuania, color=green!70!blue]{8.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{9.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.3}
\bcbar[label=Slovenia, color=green!70!blue]{10.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{8.5}
\end{bchart}
\begin{bchart}[max = 55, step = 10, scale=0.5]
\bcbar{22.1}
\bcbar[label=Belgium, color=green!70!blue]{7.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{8.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.8}
\bcbar[label=Poland, color=green!70!blue]{7.7}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{7.5}
\smallskip
\bcbar{20.4}
\bcbar[label=Sweden, color=green!70!blue]{7.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{7.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{11.3}
\bcbar[label=Netherlands, color=green!70!blue]{7.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.9}
\smallskip
\bcbar{21.7}
\bcbar[label=Romania, color=green!70!blue]{5.8}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.8}
\smallskip
\bcbar{17.3}
\bcbar[label=Hungary, color=green!70!blue]{7.0}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.8}
\smallskip
\bcbar{16.6}
\bcbar[label=Luxembourg, color=green!70!blue]{7.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{13.1}
\bcbar[label=Estonia, color=green!70!blue]{6.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{10.8}
\bcbar[label=Denmark, color=green!70!blue]{6.4}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{6.2}
\smallskip
\bcbar{10.6}
\bcbar[label=Austria, color=green!70!blue]{5.3}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.7}
\smallskip
\bcbar{11.8}
\bcbar[label=Malta, color=green!70!blue]{5.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{14.6}
\bcbar[label=United Kingdom, color=green!70!blue]{5.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.3}
\smallskip
\bcbar{12.6}
\bcbar[label=Czech Republic, color=green!70!blue]{6.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{5.1}
\smallskip
\bcbar{7.2}
\bcbar[label=Germany, color=green!70!blue]{4.2}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.6}
\smallskip
\bcbar{9.9}
\bcbar[label=Norway, color=green!70!blue]{4.0}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.4}
\smallskip
\bcbar{8.8}
\bcbar[label=Iceland, color=green!70!blue]{4.1}
\bcbar[color=red!50]{4.0}

\matrix [
   above left,
   overlay,
    every node/.style={
       anchor=west,
       font=\bcfontstyle}
   ] at ([xshift=5cm]current bounding box.south east) {
 \filldraw [draw=black,fill=blue!20] (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.7,0.25); & \node{Something}; \\
 \filldraw [draw=black,fill=green!70!blue] (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.7,0.25); & \node{Something else}; \\
 \filldraw [draw=black,fill=red!50] (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.7,0.25); & \node{Something weird}; \\
};
\end{bchart}
\caption{Unemployment rate: 2015}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]